# Cgroups unrecognised service

Tags: services, cgroups

I'm running the following command, after having modified my version of `/etc/cgconfig.conf` but get the following error (I'm running Ubuntu 14.04). Does anyone have any idea why this is the case?

```
$ sudo service cgconfig restart
cgconfig: unrecognized service
```

Comment: See this Q&A from SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21337522/trying-to-use-cgroups-in-debian-wheezy-and-no-daemons